# Cordova Plugins and dependencies

Tags: ios, cordova, audio, mobile, plugins

I would like to create a Cordova plugin for iOS that uses other pre made Cordova plugin and modifies it.

For example i want to create a plugin that uploads an audio file of type mp3 now i want to record , stop recording , play , stop play of the audio file using the "Media" plugin that provides these basic functionalities how ever with a different file format (the default media plugin uses Wav format i want to use mp3) without modifying the "Media" plugin itself.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to achieve this is Inheritance (from the native code not the js).

Create a custom plugin of your own (the same file structure as a normal Cordova plugin with a plugin.xml file, WWW folder, Src etc).

In you plugin.xml file declare Media plugin as a dependency and it will be brought dynamically to your project when you install your custom plugin (Please note depending on the version of Cordova you have on your machine the "Media" plugin native code may have some differences).

```
<dependency id="org.apache.cordova.media"/>
```

The "Media" plugin class (IOS) is called "CDVSound" when you create your own class name it CDVYourClass and make it a subclass of CDVSound.

From here you can override the methods you want to change (like if you want to record .m4a file instead of an .WAV that is the default for the Media plugin).

For more information about building a Cordova plugin plugin please refer to the Cordova documentation.

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide/cli/

And here is a good reading on custom plugins.

http://docs.telerik.com/platform/appbuilder/cordova/using-plugins/using-custom-plugins/making-plugman-compatible/create-modify-plugin-xml

Adding to this answer there are some "Private" methods that you cannot initially override to overcome this use Objective C categories to extend the parent class (CDVSound in this case) and then declare it on the category .m file afterwards you can import the category class to your parent class and override the private method.